# On the Lie derivatives along time-dependent vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

I was stimulated by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81264/6752).

On a smooth manifold $M$, an isotopy $\phi:(t,m)\in \mathbb{R}\times M\mapsto\phi_t(m)\in M$, generates the time dependent vector field $X:(t,m)\in\mathbb{R}\times M\mapsto X_t(M)=\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{s=t}(\phi_s\circ\phi_t^{-1})(m)\in TM$.

The flow of $X$ is the map $\psi_{s,t}=\phi_s\circ\phi_t^{-1}:m\in M\mapsto\phi_s(\phi_t^{-1}(m))\in M$.
For a tensor field $T$ on $M$ its Lie derivative along the time dependent vector field $X_t$ is given by: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\psi_{t,s}^\ast T)=\psi_{s,t}^\ast(\mathcal{L}(X_t).T).$$

> Concerning this expression I suppose that in general, in this context, $\mathcal{L}(X_t).(\psi_{s,t}^\ast T)\neq\psi_{s,t}^\ast(\mathcal{L}(X_t).T)$, but I don't know an example exhibiting such inequality.
>   Probably it is silly but my question is: where I can look for such an example?